# Google App Scripts Highlight Selected Text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm writing an app script and I'm trying to make a function that highlights a particular piece of text. The result of the code is that I'm highlighting the entire line instead of just the text.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
function myFun4(){
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if(selection){
    var el = selection.getRangeElements();
    Logger.log(el[0].getElement().getAttributes());
    var el0 = el[0].getElement();
    Logger.log(el0.asText());
    var highlightStyle = {};
    highlightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
    highlightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#FFFF00';
    el0.setAttributes(highlightStyle);   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to highlight the selected text on Google Document.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

When you use this script, please select a text on Google Document and run the script.

```js
function myFun4(){
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if(selection){
    selection.getRangeElements().forEach(e => {
      var range = [e.getStartOffset(), e.getEndOffsetInclusive()];
      e.getElement().asText()
        .setBackgroundColor(...range, '#FFFF00')
        .setBold(...range, true);
    });
  }
}
```

- In this modification, the background color and bold are reflected to the selected text using the methods of `setBackgroundColor(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, color)` and `setBold(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, bold)`.
- In your script, the style of paragraph is changed. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

#### References:

- [setBackgroundColor(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setbackgroundcolorstartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-color)
- [setBold(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, bold)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setboldstartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-bold)

Comment: Awesome! I have not seen `...range` before, I'm not sure what is happening there. But it works and is awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @gus Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `...range`, `...` is the spread syntax. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) In the above script, `...range` means `e.getStartOffset(), e.getEndOffsetInclusive()`.